# как вернуться обратно в цикл(условно) для проверки?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я хочу, чтобы пользователь выбрал только первое или второе значение, если он введёт что-то другое, то появится надпись, что нужно выбрать что-то одно из предоставленного...Думаю, что нужно использовать цикл for, но пока что не представляю, как это сделать. В коде я указал комментариями, в чём я не могу разобраться

```
tool = input()
tool_des = 1 
while tool_des == 1: 
if tool == str(1):
    tool = "Ручка"
    print("Что ж, ты выбрал ручку, похвально!")
    tool_des = 0
elif tool == str(2):
    tool = "Нож"
    print("Что ж, ты выбрал нож, похвально!")
    tool_des = 0
elif tool == # что нужно сюда написать, если пользователь введет что-то рандомное? 
    print("Ты не следуешь моим указаниям, выбери что-то одно...")
    print ("1)ручка \n2)нож")
    tools_des = 1
    #loop, не знаю, как вернуться снова на проверку, а goto использовать в коде не хочу
 print(tools)
input()
```

Comment: Нужно написать просто else

Comment: ничего писать не надо, надо содержимое цикла while сдвинуть на отступ и input перенести в цикл

Comment: @Эникейщик, когда пишу else, он не возвращается опять на проверку, и программа останавливается

Comment: Не может такого быть. Значит, пишешь не там.

Comment: виноват, конечно, надо elif поменять на else. Но остальное верно :)

Comment: @Эникейщик, в моём случае - программа зациклилась:(

Comment: @DenisRudnitskiy так именно это же и требуется

Comment: Аа, ну инпут надо поставить в цикл перед первым иф.

Comment: @splash58, пытался изменить на else, программа зацикливается :(

Comment: в общем, проще написать код

Comment: Использовать goto и не получилось бы. В питоне  такое отсутствует.

Comment: @splash58, это то что я и хотел увидеть;)

Comment: @Эникейщик, я знаю, поэтому и не использовал;)

Comment: @Эникейщик, может у меня рейтинга мало, а может мозгов, но я не нашел галочку общий ответ :)

Comment: @splash58 да тут такой вопрос через день бывает :). В смысле про цикл.

Comment: @Эникейщик, ну мне же нужно как-то разобраться со своей проблемой в коде:) та и я изучаю его всего 1,5 дня

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После безуспешный попыток с @Эникейщик объяснить в комментариях, пишу сюда

```
tool_des = 1 
while tool_des == 1: 
  tool = input()
  if tool == '1':
    tool = "Ручка"
    print("Что ж, ты выбрал ручку, похвально!")
    tool_des = 0
  elif tool == '2':
    tool = "Нож"
    print("Что ж, ты выбрал нож, похвально!")
    tool_des = 0
  else :
    print("Ты не следуешь моим указаниям, выбери что-то одно...")
    print ("1)ручка \n2)нож")
    #loop, не знаю, как вернуться снова на проверку, а goto использовать в коде не хочу
print(tool)
```